# How to show navigation route on Google Map?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2, google-polyline, android-navigation

I am developing an app where I am using a MapFragment. I am loading google Maps v2 into my app which is working fine. Now, I want to display a coloured line between starting point and ending point just like the navigation app in android shows, along with the animated navigation marker.

In short, I want to show the navigation app in my fragment whenever the user chooses the start and end-points.

[image]

This is the screenshot of my app. As you can see I have placed a few markers. Now I want to show the navigation route on my map.